# Sharing routing between different React Apps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm having a react-redux proto similar to the following

```
    html
   <body>
      <div id="app1"></div>
      <div id="app2"></div>
    </body>
```

There is 2 living app sharing a same store but rendered in different div. The React code does something like this

```
    Js
        ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={ store }>
          <Component1 />
        </Provider>,
          document.getElementById('app1')
        );

        ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={ store }>
          <Component2 />
        </Provider>,
          document.getElementById('app2')
        );
```

What if i need to implement a shared react-routing system where when a change occurs in app1 and modifies the URL, it gets passed to app2 and update it accordingly as well...something like this

```
Js
        ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={ store }>
           <Router history={ browserHistory }>
            <Route path="/(:param)" component={ Component1 } />
           </Router>
        </Provider>,
          document.getElementById('app1')
        );

        ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={ store }>
          <Route path="/" component={ App2 }>
           <Route path="/otherRoute(/:otherParam)" component={ Component2 } />
          </Route>          
        </Provider>,
          document.getElementById('app2')
        );
```

So action in Component1 would call Route /otherRoute(/:otherParam) valid for component2 and trigger render in Component2

Is it even possible with React / Redux to do something this viable?

Answer (score 1):

looks like the best approach for this unusual matter is not using react-router and directly implement a custom router using the library history (on which react-router is based). Some more resources

[Simple Routing with Redux and React](http://jamesknelson.com/simple-routing-redux-react/#parsing-uris)

[You might not need React Router](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/you-might-not-need-react-router-38673620f3d#.5cwst381k)